# Background image not showing up on the website

Tags: html

I am trying to place a background image but it does not appear. Please guide.

```
    <header style="    background-image: url("header.png")";
"><p>Test</p>
        </header>
```

Comment: Guide: Open your browser console, inspect the element and see if the path to the image is correct.

Comment: Guide #2: If so, check if the element has defined dimensions (`width` and `height`).

Comment: Tip: This kind of question (unclear) will attract not answers, but just downvotes.

Comment: Also, you have a mix of open/close double quotes.

Comment: Do you actually know what you're doing?

Answer (score 1):

It's obviously that you have a typo mistake or missing the image. You can use this code snippet:

Inline CSS:

```
<header style="width: 360px; height: 150px; background-image: url('http://placehold.it/360x150');">
  <p>Test</p>
</header>
```

External CSS:

```css
header {
  width: 360px;
  height: 150px;
  background: url("http://placehold.it/360x150");
}
```

```html
<header>
  <p>Test</p>
</header>
```

Comment: Assumptions should be posted as comments, not answers.

Answer (score 0):

You have some syntax errors. Also, you must set a height for it.

```html
<header style="background-image: url('http://img.bananity.com/media/512/512/bananities/8060a5cf4f9eae8ecff79720db58c2dfacf707344fcb.png'); background-size: cover; height: 400px; border: 1px solid red;">
    <p>Test</p>
</header>
```

Comment: Assumptions should be posted as comments, not answers.

Comment: Excuse me officer @MelanciaUK, I was distracted. I will edit the sentence I wrote and turn it into a non-assumption

Comment: Any answer to this question until the OP edits it and provides more information, will be just guesses. That's what I meant. The issue can be anywhere. Image path, element dimensions, the already spotted wrong syntax...